# Enable a button if one of two conditions is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im working on this form that depending on whats selected on a combobox, either another combobox or an input field is shown. And the button should be **disabled until something is selected on that combobox or the length of the input is longer than 3**. And I cant get that last bit to work.

I tried this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" :disabled="clientNumberInput.length < 3 || selectedClient === null">{{labels.lblButtonSearch}}</button>
```

And this computed property:

```
searchButtonEnabler() {
    if (this.clientNumberInput.length < 3 || this.selectedClient === null)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

But its not working. I believe it is because of how OR works in Javascript. But I cant think of any other way to do it.

EDIT: As requested, im adding the input field code.

```
<input v-if="selectedSearchByFilter != null && selectedBusiness.id == 3 && selectedSearchByFilter.id == 2"
                           name="clientNumber"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           v-model="clientNumberInput"/>
```

The value of clientNumberInput is updated through the v-model. I have two p tags showing the values of clientNumberInput and selectedClient and they are working as intended.

Comment: I noticed that your function example uses "this" but the first example does not use "this".

Comment: @JoelFan there is no this in templates (it's implicit).

Joaquin: Both sound good. Can you show the input and how clientNumberInput is updated please?

Comment: If you have the Vue devtools extension installed in your browser, inspect the value of `clientNumberInput` and `selectedClient`; I suspect `selectedClient` isn't `null` exactly (maybe it's `undefined` or an empty string or something else like that).

Comment: @Renaud Sure, i edited the post.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Sadly the framework we are using doesnt have Vue devtools enabled. But im showing the values in p tags and selectedClient is null when the combobox is left untouched.

Comment: @JoaquinLeon Simplify the disabled condition to pinpoint the exact cause. First verify that just `:disabled="selectedClient === null"` works. Also ensure that you have declared `selectedClient` and `clientNumberInput` upfront in the `data` section of your component.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I have selectedClient: null and clientNumberInput: null in the data, and the properties are updated accordingly when using the input or checkbox. I already tried isolating the conditions using two different buttons and they worked fine, the OR seems to be the issue.

Comment: @JoaquinLeon If `clientNumberInput` is null then I would expect an error when trying to access the `.length` property, can you confirm that?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yes, my bad. Actually clientNumberInput is declared as an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially misunderstood "disabled until something is selected on that combobox or the length of the input is longer than 3".
Actually you need `clientNumberInput.length < 3 && selectedClient === null` (or `clientNumberInput.length < 3 && !selectedClient`)

The logic:

- enabled = number || client
- so: disabled = !enabled = !(number || client) = !number && !client

Comment: Yes, wow, that makes perfect sense. Thank you and thank everyone else for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This how your object should look,

```
selectedSearchByFilter: {id:2},
selectedBusiness: { id:3}
```

try this
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nitins311/ocjwbey7/2/)

Comment: The input is working fine and showing up when its supposed to. selectedSearchByFilter and selectedBusiness are objects obtained from comboboxes that are also working correctly.

The problem im having is that i cant enable the button when one of the two conditions listed in the post is met.